# Understanding an odd template behavior

Tags: c++, templates

I need to export a templated method and its specialization. It is currently in a source file, and it works fine.
I am trying to move the code to the header. Unfortunately, once I do that, the specializations aren't working anymore.

This is the current state of things:

```
struct klass
{
  template<typename T> method(T&);
  template<typename T> method(std::vector<T>&);
};

template<typename T>
void klass::method(T& value)
{
}

template<typename T>
void klass::method(std::vector<T>& value)
{
}

template<>
void klass::method<std::string>(std::string& value)
{
}
```

I think the way this is supposed to work is pretty clear.

If I am not mistaken, I should be able to export all the template and partial specialization directly to the header.

The non-partial specialization can't be in a header, and needs to stay in the source file. But it shouldn't be important because since it is instantiated, every use of klass::method should already use the specialization.

Of course, this does not happen: if I move the template and partial specialization in the header, the non-partial specialization that stayed in the source file is completely ignored.

Would you please explain to me how this needs to be done ? Do I need to move the specialization inside the header and how ?

I'm using gcc. If there is anything I should know about compatibility with msvc, I'm also interested.

Comment: You can make the functions inline or I think you can do a forward declaration (i.e. specialisation without a body, then put the body in the .cpp file).

Comment: Sorry, what partial specialization are you talking about? I don't see any here, and you cannot partially specialize a function template anyway...

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), especially with a clear subdivision of what you have in a header, what you have in a cpp file, and a concrete explanation of what you get and what you expect